# Adding awesomeFont icons to treeNodes on an Xpage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, font-awesome

I have been trying to build navigation menus and accordions with Bootstrap and awesomeFont icons on an XPage. I managed to add the icons to the accordion, but all my menus are next to instead of under each other and the icon does not stay together with the text.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<xe:accordion
    id="accordion1"
    styleClass="col-lg-3">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:basicContainerNode
            label="Menu 1"
            styleClass="fa fa-bell">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="2"
                    styleClass="fa fa-wifi">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="3"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
        <xe:basicContainerNode
            label="Menu 2"
            styleClass="fa fa-database ">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="2"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="3"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
        <xe:basicContainerNode
            label="Menu 3">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="2"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="3"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
        <xe:basicContainerNode
            label="Menu 4"
            styleClass="fa fa-lg fa-link">
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
</xe:accordion>
```

There are multiple problems with the accordion:

1. When I add an FA icon, it is rendered in its own div separate from the text.
2. The next menu item is rendered next to the Container and not under it, although it's not consistent (Menu 3 is under Menu 2)
3. The basicLeafNode does not render FA icons. (Look at the 2nd child of Menu 1. It has styleClass="fa fa-wifi".)
4. The width of the accordion should be col-lg-3, however, it is inconsistent.

Comment: Please add (parts of) your code so that we can see what you have tried to do.

Comment: You can add a picture to something like a public Dropbox folder and the post the link in the question.  That and any code snippets would go a long way.

Comment: I edited the first post to make it clearer